# Need of dynamic field in model - sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

Is there any possibiltiy to define the fields in model dynamically during execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. Long answer you can register new model dynamically or add generic fields like property1..10 and use them dynamically, but this is ugly hack.

Comment: If satisfied with the answer mark it as correct answer to close this question.